# Plone 4 apache rewrite proxy works but not showing images

Tags: apache, proxy, url-rewriting, plone

I have successfully setup plone 4 and am using apache2 rewrite and it seems to work.  The problem is that the content for the site does not show up correctly.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName elzwhere.net
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /static - [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) \
    http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/et/VirtualHostRoot/%1 [L,P]
<Proxy *>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

If you try to connect to [elzwhere.net](http://elzwhere.net) you will see what I'm talking about.  I'm not exactly sure what is going on here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try $1 instead of %1 after the VirtualHostRoot.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your rewrite rule; use `$1` for the regular expression substitution at the end there.

In future, better use the [RewriteRule Witch](http://betabug.ch/zope/witch) to construct your Zope rewrite rules, it constructs the correct rule flawlessly every time!